# How to solve "UnicodeDecodeError " wile using pandas to automate +100 .csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been trying to write a For loop to store all of the CSV files in a directory into one. The files in that directory were produced by another pandas program I wrote, and I have used "group.to_csv(f'data3/{station}.csv', index = False, encoding = "utf-8")" for them to make sure the encoding is utf-8.

The combining code I used is as follows:

```
import os import pandas as pd

master_df =  pd.DataFrame() directory_path = '/pandas learning/data3'

for file in os.listdir (directory_path):
    pd.read_csv(f'data3/{file}')
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        master_df = master_df.append(pd.read_csv(f'data3/{file}'))

master_df.to_csv("final.csv" )
```

when I run the program, it gives me a UnicodeDecodeError, and since this code is for about 100 files I can't go and change the encoding of them 1 by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [**`pandas.DataFrame.append`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is deprecated, use [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) instead :

```
import os
import pandas as pd

directory_path = '/pandas learning/data3'

data=[]
for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        temp = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_path, f), enconding='xxxx')
        data.append(temp)

master_df = pd.concat(data)

master_df.to_csv("final.csv" )
```

**Note** : Make sure to put the encoding that correspond to your `.csv` files (eg. `utf-8`, `ansi`, `utf-8-sig`, ..)